# Google Visualization data.join method leads to tooltips being removed

Tags: javascript, charts, dataset, google-visualization, tooltip

I'm merging two datasets using the `google.visualization.data.join` method. This works well apart from one of the data columns seemingly being deleted in the process.

More specifically, my datasets are built like this:

```
var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();

data1.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data1.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
data1.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});

// Similar code for data2
```

I then proceed to join the two datasets like this:

```
var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]], [1], [1]);
```

And then initialize the chart like this:

```
// Create and draw the visualization.
var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(
document.getElementById('chart-div'));
chart.draw(joinedData, {
    interpolateNulls: true,
    title: 'Test',
    width: 600, height: 400,
    vAxis: {title: "cr", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}},
    hAxis: {title: "time", titleTextStyle: {color: "green"}},
    lineWidth: 1}
);
```

For some reason the tooltips are no longer visible when I hoved the mouse over the data rows. They were visible when I just presented one set alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to include tooltip column indexes in the [`join`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_join) method

```
google.visualization.data.join(dt1, dt2, joinMethod, keys, dt1Columns, dt2Columns);
```

`dt1Columns` & `dt2Columns` should be an array of column indexes you want included in the new table

```
var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(
  data1, data2, 'full', [[0, 0]],

  // include tooltip column(s) from data table 1 here
  [1, 2],

  // include tooltip column(s) from data table 2 here
  [1, 2]
);
```